# Using get_file_contents to get info from a page?

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have been searching all over the internet on how I could get the contents of a webpage and then use the information and add it to a database. I finally found get_file_contents. Except I need to be able to not only take the entire contents, I also need to be able to translate the information into variables to add to a database. It also has to support multiple people to be added to the database.
Can someone help me with this? http://www.pixelhoster.net/api/m-shopping-purchases/m/4087396 is the link of the API of the page.

Comment: So you want to write a... parser?

Comment: @resorath But how would I do that?

Comment: This is probably the most asked question on Stack Overflow... search around first and you will find everything you need to know from how to scrape, how to parse(not with regex), and how to do mysql variables.

Comment: Without knowing anything about what your trying to parse I couldn't tell you. Although I'll give you this much: trying to parse a website can be very challenging if it is not set up to be parsed.

Comment: Just gave the API link. The owner of the site has told me that it would be easy to get the info, but he never told me how.

Comment: @Will Renfroe: This question is too complex for SO.  IE: answers would require writing the entire parser for you and would require knowing the exact XML structure of this particular service.  But, do check out PHP's CURL lib (http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to connect and fetch the data, and a few XML parsing libs (http://us2.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) for starters on how to build your own.

Comment: I know that this is a really stupid question guys, but I didn't know where else to turn. :(

Comment: @Will Renfroe: for the future, please specify the content type of the external source you want to work with rather than posting its link.  Just telling us it's a simple JSON encoded string vs an XML tree will help us just the same.  I'd rather not click on any untrusted external link to figure that out myself.

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer I didn't know what JSON was as of 10 minutes ago :P But I do now!

Comment: The problem with it all was that I didn't know what I was dealing with. Not that I didn't do the propper research. If I knew it was JSON, I could have done this easily myself with a bit of google. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is a very common question on SO.
But im feeling nice:

```
<?php 
//Get the json string from the api
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.pixelhoster.net/api/m-shopping-purchases/m/4087396');

//Decode that string, true to decode into an array
$data = json_decode($data,true);

print_r($data);
/*Echos 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 917115
                    [username] => Fiskarbengtson
                )

            [item_name] => VIP
            [item_price] => 15.00
            [purchase_date] => 1330322376
            [currency] => USD
            [item_id] => 1639
            [custom_field] => 
        )

)

*/

//So to access the array 
echo $data[0]['user']['username'];
echo $data[0]['item_name'];
?>
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Lucky @WillRenfroe, my answer was just a link to the documentation.

Comment: And I would just change the value of [0] to support multiple users? And to turn 'user' and 'username' into a variable would I say $User = $data[0]['user']; ?

Comment: im not sure what you mean with multiple users, its dependent on what the api returns, if you set `$User = $data[0]['user'];` this would add the array part `user_id && username` to `$User` eg: `$User['username'] or $User['user_id']` i suggest you get familiar with http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php good luck, thanks for the accept

Answer (score 1):

The "API" link you posted seems to return data in JSON format. So, you should consider using your `file_get_contents` trick with the [json_deocde](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function.